# array of closures in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, closures

The following Rust code tries to store a closure of zero arguments in an array and call the function.

```
fn main() {
    println!("The answer is: {}", solution_fns[0]());
}

const solution_fns: [fn() -> isize] =
    [|| (1..=999).filter(|e| divides(3, e) || divides(5, e)).sum()];

fn divides(d: usize, n: usize) -> bool {
    n % d == 0
}
```

[Link to Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22The%20answer%20is%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20solution_fns%5B0%5D())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20solution_fns%3A%20%5Bfn()%20-%3E%20isize%5D%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%7C%7C%20(1..%3D999).filter(%7Ce%7C%20divides(3%2C%20e)%20%7C%7C%20divides(5%2C%20e)).sum()%5D%3B%0A%0Afn%20divides(d%3A%20usize%2C%20n%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20n%20%25%20d%20%3D%3D%200%0A%7D%0A). Unfortunately it does not compile:

> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[fn() -> isize]` cannot be
> known at compilation time  --> src/main.rs:5:21   | 5 | const
> solution_fns: [fn() -> isize] =   |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time   |   =
> help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[fn() -> isize]`

I understand that you cannot constuct an array (or Vec) of things of which the size is not known at compile-time. However I understand the type `[fn() -> isize]` to be array of function pointers, and I don't see why a function pointer should not have a known size. Sticking the closure in a Box does not seem to help:

```
const solution_fns: [Box<fn() -> isize>] = [Box::new(|| {
    (1..=999).filter(|e| divides(3, e) || divides(5, e)).sum()
})];
```

How then can I store an array of closures?

Comment: The type `fn() -> isize` has a known size – it's simply a pointer. The problem is that `[T]` does not have a known size. Try `[T; N]` with `N` being the number of closures instead, or use `Vec<T>` and the `vec![]` macro.

Comment: See also this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28175750).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an array in Rust function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164456/how-to-return-an-array-in-rust-function)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in the fn pointer, but that your array doesnt have a size. It is simply solved by adding the expected size to the array declaration:

```rust
const solution_fns: [fn() -> usize; 1] =
    [|| (1..=999usize).filter(|&e| divides(3, e) || divides(5, e)).sum()];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38fd24f7f21471adc76b9b8e0a745056)

Comment: I see that I seem to have misinterpreted the error message. Thanks for setting me straight. Is it possible to make the compiler infer the length of the array?

Comment: @hkBst Unfortunately, in a `static`/`const`, you cannot, only in `let`s

Comment: Apparently you can do this: `const SOLVERS: &[fn() -> usize] = &[|| (1..=999).filter(|&e| divides(3, e) || divides(5, e)).sum()];`

Comment: Better yet, just make up a number N and say the array is [T; N], then the LSP will tell you if N is wrong and it will tell you actual number of elements in the array so you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a slice, then you don't have to specify the size:

```
fn main() {
    println!("The answer is: {}", SOLVERS[0]());
}

const SOLVERS : &[fn() -> usize] =
    &[|| (1..=999).filter(|&e| divides(3, e) || divides(5, e)).sum()];

fn divides(d: usize, n: usize) -> bool {
    n % d == 0
}
```

[Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a88444d07da602ed1d23c01f5406df4a).